# Using the definition of derivatives.

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function such that $f(x) = f(1-x)$, for all real numbers $x$. If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then $f'(0) =$ ?

In order to solve this, I thought using the definition of $f'(x)|_{x=0}$ was useful,
so I tried to figure out $$\lim_{h\to0}{ {f(x+h)-f(x)}\over{h}}$$
when $x = 0$ knowing that $f(x)$ has a period of 1.

I also understand that since $f$ is differentiable, so it must be continuous, therefore the mean value theorem also states that there exists a value $c$ in $(x-1,x)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

I've tried to combine these ideas, but I could not get any good answer.

It is a choice among $\pm f(0),\pm f'(0), \text{ and} f''(0)$.

Comment: I suspect $f'(0)$ is determined. For example, $f(x)=(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$ and $f(x)=2(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$ have different derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: Note that $f$ does not have a period of $1$; rather, it is symmetric in the line $x=\frac12$. As @Easy meant to say, that means that $f\,'(0)$ is not determined: for any $a\in\Bbb R$ there is a differentiable function $f$ symmetric in the line $x=\frac12$ whose derivative at $0$ is $a$. The most you can say without further information is that $f\,'(0)=-f\,'(1)$.

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to ask $f'(1/2)$ instead? Or, the hypothesis were $f(x)=f(-x)$...

Comment: @Berci: It would certainly make a lot more sense to ask for the derivative at $1/2$; that would be a nice little problem.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.

From your ideas I think what the problem wanted me to figure out is that the graph is symmetric about the line x = 1/2. Therefore $f'(0) = -f'(0)$.